# Is there a way of getting WordPerfect Reveal Codes in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, wordperfect

I really like the Reveal Codes function in WordPerfect. Are there any free add-ins that can add this functionality to Word 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a program called [CrossEyes](http://www.levitjames.com/Products/CrossEyes.aspx). It is free and does something close to what I want.

Answer (score 1):

[Word doesn't really work the same way as WordPerfect](http://word.mvps.org/FAQs/General/RevealCodes.htm), as WordPerfect uses an approach more like HTML which is what you're looking at the in the Reveal Codes screen.

You can try to turn on the various options which show formatting.  The `Paragraph` box on the `Home` tab has a pilcrow (¶) that you can click, and the `Word Options` dialog box under the orb has a display tab which lets you set what the ¶ does.

Answer (score 1):

Another helpful feature for WordPerfect users to know about in Microsoft Word is the "Reveal Formatting" feature, accessed via SHIFT+F1. It gives a summary of all the formatting that has been applied at the insertion point. If a range of text has been selected, it will show you the formatting common to all of the selection.

This doesn't give you the same level of control over document formatting as you get in WordPerfect, but it can help you puzzle out why the format isn't what you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

I have WordPerfect X6, which gives the user the option of using WordPerfect in a Word or Word Perfect format. (You can use WordPerfect to make psuedo-Word documents.) If you open a Word file with WordPerfect, you can view the reveal codes in the Word document exactly like they are viewed in a WordPerfect document.

Just find the Word file you want to open in Windows Explorer, right-click and choose "open with" and then select WordPerfect.

I know that this feature is not new in this version (X6) of WordPerfect, but I do not know how many versions back it started.